# Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I'm unable to work out why I'm getting an Error 13 with the following code - more specifically at line 8 (dStDev = Round(Application.StDev(rngGrainSummary), 3))

```
    Dim i As Long                   'generic counter
Dim nColumns As Long            'number of grain sizes to plot
Dim iSeries As Series           'i-th series
Dim nSeries As Long             'total number of series
Dim rngIDNode As Range          'ID node of data worksheet
Dim rngGrainSummary As Range    'range including all current grain size data
Dim rngLimitNode As Range       'last specification cell of data worksheet


  'find the stats by moving rngGrainSummary right incrementally
'rounding necessary due to constraint on string length of absolutely assigned y values
For i = 1 To nColumns
    Set rngGrainSummary = rngGrainSummary.Offset(0, 1)
    dMean(i) = Round(Application.Average(rngGrainSummary), 3)
    dMax(i) = Round(Application.Max(rngGrainSummary), 3)
    dMin(i) = Round(Application.Min(rngGrainSummary), 3)
    dStDev = Round(Application.StDev(rngGrainSummary), 3)
    dStDevAbove(i) = dMean(i) + dStDev
    dStDevBelow(i) = dMean(i) - dStDev
Next
```

I'm not sure what else I can add that will be of any help to you all. Please help!

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: _I'm not sure what else I can add..._ you could include the definitions of your variables.  Your error might be because you havn't used `dStDev(i)`, hard to tell without the definitions.

Comment: What is the initial reference of `rngGrainSummary`? If it is a single cell then the above code refers to one cell as well, and `stdev` will return an error.

Comment: It's confusing as we've got a number of s/sheets that use the same code without problem. Very odd.

Comment: Also when I try 'dStDev(i)' I get a "Compile Error: Expected Array"

Comment: Have you tried unpicking rngGrainSummary in the debugger? Try 1: Dim test as Variant 2: test = rngGrainSummary.Value then look at test in the watch window. If there are any non-numeric values in that variant then I'd suggest that's where your problem lies.

Comment: If the range had non-numeric values then I guess the `average` would throw an error before `stdev`? If the range is a single cell then`stdev` will give an `Error 2007` and `Round()` will throw a `Run-time error 13`, which is the reported error. Its hard to tell without knowing what `rngGrainSummary` is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rngGrainSummary required AT LEAST two sets of data to interpret. Code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps StDev is returning an error value rather than a Double

Comment: We found out what the answer was after much wailing and gnashing of teeth - there needed to be two rows of data in rngGrainSummary. Thank you all for your help!